# require at least one checkbox with nested names

Tags: jquery, validation, checkbox

**Update: I found out my added method was not being called because I was calling addClassRules for my form class. I don't know why I can't do that, but I fixed it by adding a hidden form field with no value and apply the custom validation to that field.**

I have a section of my form where I am requiring at least on checkbox be checked. Originally I validated with:

```
$.validator.addMethod('kegRequired', $.validator.methods.required, 'Choose at least one keg size');
$.validator.addClassRules('kegsize', {kegRequired: true});
```

Where each checkbox looked like this:

```
input class="kegsize" name="33kegsizes[]" type="checkbox" value="SixthBbl"
```

The number was an id of the parent 'vendor'.

This stopeed working when I refactored the form to look  like this

```
input class="kegsize" name="vendors[33][kegsize][SixthBbl]" type="checkbox" value="SixthBbl"
```

This ends up regarding every checkbox as required. I would like to be able to just say 'vendors[]kegsize[]': required (like this non-working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/7rjcyej6/).

Here is a different attempt, but this is not working and I'm not sure why:

```
$.validator.addMethod('kegRequired', function(value, element, params) {
    if ($(element).find('input:checked .kegsize').length()){
        return true
    }else{
        return false
    }
}, 'Choose at least one keg size');

$.validator.addClassRules('keg-size-price-form', {kegRequired: true});
```

How I can require that at least one checkbox is selected when I have the nested naming?

Comment: I just updated my question to make it a little more clear. I want to require at least one checkbox is checked using nested names.

Comment: Are you using a validation plugin?

Comment: I am using jquery validation

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try it this approach instead.

```
var $element = $(element).find('input:checked');
var $length = $element.length;

if ($length >= 1){
    return true
}else{
    return false
}
```

Comment: I tried this out with and without '.kegsize' on the input selector, still nothing firing. Also, since lenght needs to be greater than 0, I should be able to leave off >= 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [length](https://api.jquery.com/length/) instead of `length()`

```
if ($(element).find('input:checked .kegsize').length > 0){
    return true
}else{
    return false
}
```